# "Shoulder" or "shoulders"... which one should I use?

Tags: word-in-context

In the phrase below:

> I'm not here to cry on nobody's shoulder/shoulders, I just want you to
>   pay the money you owe me.

The correct is to use "shoulder" or "shoulders"? Or I could use either one and it would make no difference?

Comment: I personally thing you can use either. This is speech, so you already have a double negative that needs to be ignored (It would mean *I'm here to cry on someone's shoulder(s)* otherwise which is clearly not what is meant). You can cry on someone's shoulder or shoulders. Literally you would cry on one shoulder, figuratively you could cry on a persons shoulders (not a specific one).

Comment: Thank you a lot for all the information, Smock. Please, let me ask you something. In Portuguese we constantly use double negative - it's grammatically wrong but we use it all the time anyway. I did some research and I found some examples of use of double negative in English as well. Here is a link: https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-portuguese/I+don%27t+want+nobody+crying+over+me. How common is the use of this grammatically incorrect English? Do people usually use it in day by day conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [saying](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/a-shoulder-to-cry-on) goes "a shoulder to cry on", then it is better to say:

> Im not here to cry on anybody's shoulder, I just want you to pay the money you owe me.

Answer (score 1):

A shoulder to cry on, whether its on the left side or on the right side.

Since one's head can not rest on the entire shoulder blade then I think it is correct to say "a shoulder" to cry on.